# How to preinstall a Windows 7 device driver or prevent install prompt?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I am trying to silently install Cisco IP Communicator software as part of a system deployment.  For deployment, I am using KACE 2000 which basically lets you compile sets batch files and run them in a specific order after the OS is installed.

For IP Communicator, I am using the installer switches to do a silent install, and that works, but the problem I am facing is that midway through the installation, Windows throws up a device driver install confirmation dialog box.  If I manually click to allow the installation then the install proceeds fine and eventually concludes.  I suspect this problem would apply to any software which installs its own drivers, so there must be some workarounds.

I want to remove this user interaction because we typically batch deploy a bunch of systems at the same time.  The deployment takes 30-45 minutes or so, and we don't want to have to monitor the deployment, we just want to be able to start 5 or 10 computers deploying, come back in an hour and have all of them be done.

Since it seems like this is a Windows prompt, I don't think Cisco would be able to help me overcome this issue.

Two possible solutions I thought of are 1) somehow preinstall the driver before installing CIPC, or 2) disable prompting when installing 3rd party drivers.

Option 1 would be my preference from a security perspective, unless there is some way to whitelist drivers on a case by case basis so the user won't receive a prompt when installing specific drivers.  Ideally, I'm looking for a way to preload the driver from the command line or by using vbscript/powershell/WSH in some way that wouldn't result in a driver installation prompt itself.

I am working Win7 Pro SP1 x64.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you would like to add an sort of exception for Windows to allow device driver installation automatically for this device?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I ended up using was preloading the certificates that were used to digitally sign the driver.  If those certificates are in the computers certificate store then the driver installation prompt will not be displayed.